# Mean of $X_i\sim Ber(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$ converges to zero

Tags: probability, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_i\sim Ber\left(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}\right)$, that is $X_i=1$ with a probability of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and $X_i=0$ with a probability of $1-\frac
{1}{\sqrt{n}}$.
I wish to show that $P(|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i|>\varepsilon)\rightarrow 0$ for any $\varepsilon>0$. May I use the weak law of large numbers as the expected value is $\frac
{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ and variance is finite? What confuses me is that usually the expected value is fixed. If not, what other approach can I use to show the desired fact?

Comment: [Markov's inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov%27s_inequality) may be enough.  Try to show that for any positive $\epsilon, \delta$, there is an $N_0$ such that for all $n>N_0$ you have $P(|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i|>\varepsilon)< \delta$ by finding a suitable $N_0$ based on $\epsilon, \delta$

Comment: I think you want to say $X_n$ is $Ber (\frac 1 {\sqrt n})$.

Comment: It seems likely that you have copied the problem wrongly, but I have answered the question in the present form as well the corrected form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no assumption of independence, so Law Of Larage Numbers is not applicable.

Proof when $X_i \sim B(\frac 1{\sqrt i})$ for every $i$:

$E(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i)=\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nEX_i=\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac 1 {\sqrt i}$. Comparison of $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n \frac 1 {\sqrt i}$ with $\int_0^{n}\frac 1 {\sqrt x}$ shows that $E(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i) \to 0$. This implies that $\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i \to 0$ in probability (use Markov's inequality and non-negativity of $X_i$'s) which is what we have to prove.

Proof when $X_i \sim B(\frac 1{\sqrt n})$: In this case $E(\frac{1}{n}\sum\limits_{i=1}^nX_i)=\frac 1 {\sqrt n} \to 0$ so the conlcusion holds.

Comment: Shouldn't the expected value be $\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}$ instead of $\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}}$, which means it sums up to $\sqrt{n}$, and $\frac{\sqrt{n}}{n}$ still goes to zero?

Comment: It is not true in total generality that if the expected value of a sequence of r.v.s tends to zero then the sequence converges to zero in probability

Comment: Our random variables are non-negative, so we get $L^{1}$ convergence. . @FShrike

Comment: @kern711 If you look at the comments under your question then you'll see people asking about that.

Answer (score 1):

Since $X_i\sim Ber(\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}})$, we have
$$
 E\left( \left| \frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i\right| \right)= E\left(\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^n X_i \right)=\frac 1 n \sum_{i=1}^nE\left( X_i \right)= \frac 1 n \cdot n \cdot \frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}
$$
and Markov's inequality yields
$$
    P(|\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^nX_i|>\varepsilon) \le \frac{1}{\varepsilon\sqrt{n}}.
$$
As the $X_i$ on the left hand side are different random variables for each $n$, letting $n\to\infty$ would be formally clearer, if we read $X_i=X_{n,i}$. Then, this calculation yields that
$$
  \frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n X_{n,i} \xrightarrow{n\to\infty} 0 \quad \text{in probability.}
$$

Comment: This looks like a copy of my answer. Is there anything new here?

Comment: It is a copy of my (now deleted) comment that I turned into an answer. At that time, your answer was still working only with the assumption that the OP actually meant $X_i\sim Ber(\frac{1}{\sqrt{i}})$. I decided to answer the question as asked.